# Exporting Mongoose methods in Node.js (TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've created a simple todo checklist website, where users can view `"Today's"` todo lists (on Home page), add new items to the list, create and delete other todo lists. All my code worked perfectly.
So I decided to refactor the code to separate the Mongoose (MongoDB) code into a separate module called `model.js`, from the `app.js` file (where the HTTP methods are handled).

Now, my Home page still loads on the browser, however, Nodemon shows that the app crashes in the terminal. If I select any option on the website, the page just doesn't display anything. So since my app is crashing on the Home route, I've placed `console.log` statements within `app.get('/' ...` api, and any methods it calls from the `model.js` file, in order to try to debug the issue, but to no avail.

Before I share my code, just to note that I only shared the `app.get('/' ...` and `app.post('/'...` code from `app.js` file, since the app is crashing on the Home page, and all of the code from the `model.js` file.

Here's my code: 
`app.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const date = require(`${__dirname}\\date.js`);
const model = require(`${__dirname}\\model.js`); 
const ejs = require('ejs');
const _ = require('lodash');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));


//*** HTTP requests' handlers

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const defaultListName = "Today's";
  const todayFormatted = date.getDate();
  model.DBUtility.findOneList(defaultListName, (foundList) => {
    console.log('inside model.DBUtility.findOneList');
    if (!foundList) {
      console.log('inside !foundList. Just before createNewListInDB');
      model.DBUtility.createNewListInDB(defaultListName);
      res.redirect('/');
    } else { 
      res.render('list', {
        listTitlePassToH1: foundList.name,
        todayDate: todayFormatted,
        listItems: foundList.items
      });
      console.log(`else render list. found list: ${foundList.name}`);
    }
    console.log('end of model.DBUtility.findOneList')
  });
  console.log(`end of app.get('/'`);
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const receivedItem = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.listName;
  model.DBUtility.addNewItemToListInDB(listName, receivedItem);
  if (listName === "Today's") {
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/' + listName);
  } 
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started, listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

model.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//create DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });


//create schema
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String
});

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemsSchema);
const List = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);


class DBUtility {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor class DBUtility");
    }

    // *** DB utility methods

    static findOneList(listName, callBack) {

        List.findOne({name: listName}, (err, foundList) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`Found list: ${foundList.name}`);
                var list = foundList; 
            } 
            callBack(list); 
        });
    }

    static findAllLists(callBack) {
        List.find({}, (err, allLists) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`Found all lists: ${allLists}`);
                callBack(allLists);
            }  
        });
    }


    static createNewListInDB(listName) {
        //create default items for new list
        const introItem = new Item({
            name: 'Welcome to your todolist!'
        });

        const addItem = new Item({
            name: 'Hit the + button to add a new item.'
        });

        const deleteItem = new Item({
            name: '<-- Hit this to delete an item.'
        });

        const listNameCap = _.capitalize(listName);
        const list = new List({
            name: listNameCap,
            items: [introItem, addItem, deleteItem]
        });
        list.save(err => {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log(`List ${list} added successfully to DB.`);
        });
    }

    static addNewItemToListInDB(listName, itemName) {
        console.log(`List passed: ${listName}`);
        List.findOne({name: listName}, (err, foundList) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                foundList.items.push({ name: itemName });
                foundList.save(err => {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
                console.log(`Item ${itemName} added to list ${listName} successfully.`);
                });
            }  
        });  
    }

    static deleteItemFromListInDB(listName, itemID) {
        // findOneAndUpdate is a mongoose method, but $pull is a mongoDB method
        List.findOneAndUpdate({name: listName}, {$pull: {items: {_id: itemID}}}, (err, updatedList) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(`deleted item "${itemID}" from list ${updatedList} successfully.`);
                    console.log(`Updated list: ${updatedList}.`);
                }
        });
    }

    static deleteOneListFromDB(listID) {
        List.findByIdAndDelete(listID, (err, deletedList) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(`Deleted list ${deletedList.name} successfully`);
        }
        });
    }
}

exports.DBUtility = DBUtility;
```

Here's the logs and error I get in Terminal:

```
Server started, listening on port: 3000 
end of app.get('/' 
Found list: Today's 
inside model.DBUtility.findOneList 
else render list. found list: Today's 
end of model.DBUtility.findOneList
events.js:288 
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Note, I have only one LIST object stored in MongoDB database, which is "Today's" todo list:

```
db.lists.find().pretty() 
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e98982a7f8b083a6cf2d433"),
        "name" : "Today's",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5e98982a7f8b083a6cf2d430"),
                        "name" : "Welcome to your todolist!"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5e98982a7f8b083a6cf2d431"),
                        "name" : "Hit the + button to add a new item."
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5e98982a7f8b083a6cf2d432"),
                        "name" : "<-- Hit this to delete an item."
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

When I deleted this object from MongoDB terminal using:

```
> db.lists.deleteOne( {name: "Today's"} ) 
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 1 }
```

Now even my Home page doesn't load anymore. I get:

```
This site can’t be reached
```

And the error in Terminal is the same, however, I'm only seeing the very last console.log statement in `app.get('/'...`

```
Server started, listening on port: 3000 
end of app.get('/' 
events.js:288 
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Also, model.js and app.js are on the same directory level:

[image]

Sorry for the long-winded post, but I wanted to make sure I'm thorough in my explanation.

**EDIT**
Here's the full error message :

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started, listening on port: 3000
end of app.get('/'
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\model.js:36:54
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4849:16
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4849:16
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4872:21
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4379:11
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4851:13
    at C:\Users\hazzaldo\Desktop\...\todolist-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Can you post whole error? It must have shown line number

Comment: Just added it in the EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

happens when you try to access 'name' property of a null object.

So the only candidates where error appears follow `obj.name` pattern.

Now when I think about it, another case would be `name` property destructuring but it if natively supported it gives another error.

Also

```js
console.log('inside !foundList. Just before createNewListInDB');
model.DBUtility.createNewListInDB(defaultListName);
res.redirect('/');
```

function `model.DBUtility.createNewListInDB(defaultListName);` is asynchronous and after it you call `res.redirect('/')`.
I don't know how `Node Express` handles this function internally but you should redirect after tasks were created.

Like

```js
model.DBUtility.createNewListInDB(defaultListName)
.then(_ => {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

--Edit

`list` variable wasn't declared outside if statement and could raise exception `list is not defined`

```js
    static findOneList(listName, callBack) {
        var list = null;

        List.findOne({name: listName}, (err, foundList) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`Found list: ${foundList.name}`);
                list = foundList; 
            } 
            callBack(list); 
        });
    }
```

Also, `const _ = require("lodash");` was not included inside `model.js`. As a `lodash` method was used inside: `static createNewListInDB(listName)` method. Line: `const listNameCap = _.capitalize(listName);`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried your suggestion. But it doesn't seem to fix the issue. The issue seems to point to `static findOneList(listName, callBack)` method in `model.js` file. At the block `if (err || !foundList) {
                console.log('Error: ${err}');
            }` it's printing the error here, with `err` printed out as `null` in the Terminal. But I'm not sure why.

Comment: All I want to do is just pass the null or undefined value to the callback, if List.findOne Mongoose method query result does not find a list object. So that I can capture this null or undefined value inside app.get('/'... method and create a new List object instead. Surely there's a way to pass null or undefined value in a callback, in Javascript? Or is it something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You mean `callBack(list);` in `static findOneList(listName, callBack)` ? You can first initialize `list` variable at the start of function as a null then it would be assigned to list in if condition if there is record in db

Comment: Awesome, that solved it, finally!! Thank you!! I've been trying to work this problem out for the last 2 days. Also I wanted to point out, the other problem was - I didn't include `const _ = require("lodash");` in `model.js`. Because a `lodash` method inside `model.js`. Just wanted to ask by the by, why is the returned query from `findOne` (`foundList`) cannot be passed directly to the callback (if there's no value) and instead we have to create a var and initialise it with `null`, and assign `foundList` to it instead, before passing it to the callback, as you suggested?

Comment: If not list was found from the query, wouldn't `foundList` just have the value `null` anyway, and we can pass that to the callback?

Comment: Also, if you could amend your answer as per what you suggested in your last comment that worked for me, so I can mark it with a green tick, so that it can help others. Thank you once again.

Comment: Generally when you try to access variable which is not defined in context it raises `variable is not defined exception`.

Comment: So when you say " access variable which is not defined", is this the same as typeof `undefined` or is this different?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error on line no 36 of model.js

```
console.log(`Found list: ${foundList.name}`)
```

you can update your code like

```
static findOneList(listName, callBack) {

        List.findOne({name: listName}, (err, foundList) => {
            if (err || !foundList) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`Found list: ${foundList.name}`);
                var list = foundList; 
            } 
            callBack(list); 
        });
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my code with your suggestion: adding `console.log('Error: ${err}')`. Just so I can identify this console log with the "Error:" string. Now I get a new error

Comment: `Server started, listening on port: 3000 
Error: null 
events.js:288 
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: So the error being printed is `null`. And also `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: Replace code of you findOneList function as given in the answer.

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue why now. As there's no LIST object created in DB, so in `List.findOne` method it's hitting the `else if (!foundList) {` statement. Now what I need to do is just pass something, like a null, or a string value `"null"` to the `callback`. So that in the `app.js` method `app.get('/' ...` I can capture what is passed to the callback and decide whether to create a new LIST object or if there's a LIST object passed to the `callback` then I can just render the EJS page.

Comment: But for some reason a null error is just thrown, rather than allowing me to pass that null value to the `callback`, so I can receive it in `app.get('/'..` method in `app.js`. How do I pass something safely to the `callback` even if `foundList` is null?